# Does anyone know a dataset for industrial network security?

Tags: ids, anomaly-detection

I'm trying to develop an intrusion detection for Industrial Ethernet. e.g. S7, PROFINET, Modbus protocols.

I want to evaluate my work on IE security dataset. Does anyone know security dataset in this domain? Some PCAP examples or sanitize dataset like KDD?